# edit delimited string with regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, csv

i have a string which i want to edit a part of it.
the string is like

"1:5,7:9,13:20,130:510,134:2,"

now all i want to do is remove the first part of those numbers like

"5,9,20,540,2,"

i tried a bunch of combinations but didn't get what i expected.

```
Regex rx = new Regex("[:]\\d+[,]");
    foreach (Match mx in rx.Matches("10:20,20:30,"))
    {
        Muhaha.InnerText += mx;
    }
```

it returns ":20,:30," but i want to capture only the number, nut the punctuation.

Comment: Regular Expressions seem like overkill for this.

Comment: yeah it is, i know. but i still wanna find out how to get this thing right.

Comment: If regex is overkill, how this should be parsed? Split by commas, find semicolon for each part and remove it? The solution with regexes (by @Aistina) is much more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `Replace` instead?

```
Regex r = new Regex("\\d+:");
string str = r.Replace("1:5,7:9,13:20,130:510,134:2,", "");
Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Prints:

```
5,9,20,510,2,
```

Comment: it worked well, thanks. ( funny.. i am pretty sure i tried to replace it before. )

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you want to manipulate that numbers before joining them (if not, you should go with [@Aistina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2201044/edit-delimited-string-with-regular-expression/2201089#2201089) answer):

```
foreach(Match m in Regex.Matches(
    "1:5,7:9,13:20,130:510,134:2,", 
    @":(?'number'\d+)"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups["number"].Value);
}
```

Comment: aren't there any simple way to avoid capturing ":" and "," ?